# Selecting,merging and outputting mysql results from a 'select where in array' query for a grocery list

Tags: php, mysql

I'm stuck trying to build a grocery list based on recipies.

I have 2 tables :

> recipe: id, recipename
>
> recipeingredient:recipeid, ingredientname, ingredientamount, ingredientmeasure

so i'm sending a list of recipie id's to mysql where i am to grab all recipeingredients.

That is simple enough :

```
 $sql = "SELECT *  FROM recipeingredient where recipeid in $vars2";
foreach loop etc
```

however, there are a couple requirements to this list that im unable to do.

1. When an id is duplicate, where in will ignore it. i need it to be queried.
2. if a recipeingredient is : `"butter 200 mg | ingredientname  ingredientamount, ingredientmeasure"` and you have 2 of those in your result, i need it to merge the amount. However, it has to distinguish between the ingredientmeasure!

**Example:**

1. butter 200 grams
2. butter 2 sticks

*outputs :* butter 200 grams, butter 2 sticks.

**Example2:**

1. butter 200 grams
2. butter 2 grams

*Outputs* : butter 202 grams

Pretty much a dynamic, complete grocerylist based on a list of recipies.

I have tried alot of different things with the queries, but i'm at a loss.
Is the best way of doing this to parse the output after querying each recipe individually?

Being new to php arrays, i dont know how to really do that..
I can do it in javascript, but bruteforcing it always bites me in the ass after a while.
Here's a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/77420/2) of it

Any pointers or help is greatly appreciated! =)

Comment: recipe_ingredient should look like this: recipe_ingredient(recipe_id*,ingredient_id*,quantity,unit [or unit_id]) `*`=(component of) PRIMARY KEY

Answer (score 1):

So, you're basically after something like this, right?

```
SELECT ingredientname
     , SUM(ingredientamount) total
     , ingredientmeasure 
  FROM recipeingredient 
 WHERE recipeid IN (7,8) 
 GROUP
    BY ingredientname
     , ingredientmeasure;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/77420/7

You could go further. For instance, a 'rasher' of bacon weighs approx. 25g, so you could factor that in to the calculation - bit of a mission though!

...and see my comment above.

To select multiples of the same recipe, you probably need to do something like this...

```
SELECT recipeid
     , ingredientname
     , ingredientamount
     , ingredientmeasure 
  FROM recipeingredient 
 WHERE recipeid IN (7,8);
```

...and then handle the rest of the logic at the application level (e.g. with a bit of php and/or javascript)

Comment: Heya, thanks for replying!  that is pretty right, but this also ignores similar id's.. so if i have 2 x recipe with id 7, it wouldnt output more than 1.

Comment: It would be like , SUM(ingredientamount*countnumberofsimilarrows)

Comment: I won't say that you *can't* do that with MySQL, but I'm not sure I know how and, besides, it's probably not appropriate to do so. That aspect of the problem is probably best handled at the application level.

Comment: ive tried a whole lot of different ways to go about this now, and i'm at a loss. thinking of bruteforcing it with jquery or something. Thanks alot for your time and help =)

Comment: Yeah, I've done something similar with JavaScript before, where I've populated a timesheet form with data from an SQL table, and then provided a real-time summary at the bottom. My point is, if I can do it, it *must* be easy!

Comment: trying with arrays now. proving that my brain actually CAN melt if i try hard enough.